# Bar3 plot increase bar thickness

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot the stacked bar3 plot. How to increases the thickness of the bars? All the bars look flat. I need something like this with thick bars stacked next to each other.

[image: What I want]

What I got was:

[image: My plot]

Below is the code and I have also attached the dependency file link [Data](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlFYM4jwmzqrs-VvyN8QYMgVM8dNsQ?e=OPclhe). Please let me know a solution.

```
clc; close all; clear;

Z1 = randi([10,500],100,3);
Z2 = randi([10,900],200,3);

class_string = {'Dataset I', 'Dataset II'};

% Plot 3D graph
hFig = figure;
h = bar3(Z1(:, 1), Z1(:, 2:end),'stacked');   
hold on;
for j=1:length(h)
  set(h(j),'xdata',get(h(j),'xdata')+2-1);
end
h2 = bar3(Z2(:, 1), Z2(:, 2:end),'stacked'); 

set(gca, 'PlotBoxAspectRatioMode','auto')
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',class_string, 'XTick', 1:2, 'FontSize', 20, 'LineWidth', 3) %, ...
ylabel ('Image resolution (kilo pixels)')
zlabel ('No.of images')
legend ('High Texture','Low Texture','Location','NorthEast');
hold off
axis tight;
```

Comment: please strip your code to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because  [MATLAB does exactly what you want](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html)

Comment: This is the minimum that I can make. I noticed that stacking multiple rows and increasing the resolution squeezes the bars. Is there a way to have thickness?

Comment: Your code is not *reproducible* (we have no data but you could just generate random points). Perhaps you can provide a truly minimal example with only two bars, no loop and no other fuzz. It can be that `hold on` ruins your plot or that the command `set(gca, 'PlotBoxAspectRatioMode','auto')` is responsible for this. When you have tided up the example and it still exhibits this error, I am happy to help =)

Comment: If the problem is that the bars are very thin along the "image resolution" axis because you have many bars along that axis, well, crowding so many bars necessarily makes them thin so they can fit. Can't you reduce the number of bars (bins) along the "image resolution" axis?

Comment: @max, here I have made a minimal example.

Comment: You have 900 bars, how do you expect them to not be thin? If you make the bars wider, they will overlap, and you still will not be able to see them. What you need to do is change the data you plot, so that you have fewer bars.

Comment: Also, 3D bars cannot be read properly, and should not be used for serious data visualization. Unless you're making a presentation for investors, and want to hide the truth from them, don't use 3D bars.

Comment: works fine for me if I strip your code further and plot less than 900 bars ;)